# How to reorder bars of a tornado graph in R?

Tags: r, plot, charts

I am trying to plot a **tornado graph** for **sensitivity analysis** purposes. This is what I have so far.

```
OP <- par(mar = c(7,7,7,7))

data <- matrix(c(-0.10,0.15,-0.01,0.01,-0.03,0.08,-0.1,0.07), ncol = 4)

# Amount of Change in Variables
rownames(data) <- c('+25%','-25%')

# Names of Variables
colnames(data) <- c('Variable 1', 'Variable 2', 'Variable 3','Variable 4')

# For Plotting % on X-Axis
x <- seq(-0.30,0.30, length=13)    

SEQUENTIAL <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(4, "YlOrRd")

barplot(data[1,], main="Tornado Graph", horiz = T, las=1, xlim = c(-0.30,0.30), xaxt='n', ylab = '', col=SEQUENTIAL)
barplot(data[2,], horiz = T, las=1, xlim = c(-0.30,0.30), xaxt='n', ylab = '', col=SEQUENTIAL, add = TRUE)

# Add x-axis
axis(1, at=x,  labels=paste0(x * 100," %"), las=TRUE)

par(OP)
```

The bars of the tornado graph are not sorted like in a proper graph. How do I **sort** them in **decreasing** length?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the columns in order for plotting.  Replace your two `barplot` statements with

```
ORD = order(data[2,] - data[1,])
barplot(data[1,ORD], main="Tornado Graph", horiz = T, las=1, 
       xlim = c(-0.30,0.30), xaxt='n', ylab = '', col=SEQUENTIAL)
barplot(data[2,ORD], horiz = T, las=1, xlim = c(-0.30,0.30), xaxt='n', 
       ylab = '', col=SEQUENTIAL, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I wanted. I wasn't far from the solution! Thanks!